# Make gdm/mdm prompt for an empty password on liveCD

Tags: password, livecd, gdm

By default Fedora liveCD is configured in a way that `liveuser` is logged in automatically since following lines added to `gdm`/`mdm` (a fork of `gdm` of GNOME2) configuration file

```
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=false
AutomaticLogin=liveuser
```

I'd like to turn off autologin and remove those lines. So after booting the liveCD I can see the user selection screen, but clicking `liveuser` forces immediate login without pausing for password prompt screen - so the user can't select language on liveCD if `liveuser` has an empty password.

I'd like to keep `liveuser` passwordless but make `gdm`/`mdm` pause on the password screen to let user select language (and DE maybe).

Is there a way to do this?